# Memory allocation warning even though workspace not saved

Tags: r, out-of-memory

I run a larger R program, but don't intend to save the workspace or anything. The program itself runs without complaints, but, when I enter quit(save = "no", status = 0, runLast = FALSE), I get the warning message

*system call failed: Cannot allocate memory*

Why does this happen? Why is R trying to allocate memory at this point? There is no more code left to run. It should just release what's still allocated and then quit.